# AS3 Flash CS6 Character Movement Both Legs

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

So I've been researching this for a while and haven't found much. I have my Player MovieClip all set up with the graphics all in place on separate frames, stop()s in another Layer on every frame, and labels for every frame in another Layer. There are different graphics for both legs for each direction (like in most tile-based games.) Here's the code for one direction.

```
    if (_inp.keyRight && isSnapped())
        {
            _moving = true;
            _directionStr = "Right";
            _directionInt = 0;
            _speed = MOVEMENT_SPEED;
            gotoAndStop("WalkRight1");
        }
```

I want it to jump to "WalkRight2" when he takes another step.

```
    if (_speed > 0 && isSnapped())
        {
            _moving = false;
            _speed = 0;
            gotoAndStop(_directionStr);
        }
```

That's how I make it go back to the Idle graphics in the direction he was last in when stopped. How do I make it jump to WalkRight2?!

Comment: Figured it out. Made a counter for my steps and then did a modulus so that if the steps are divisible by 2 without a remainder, use the left leg, else use the right.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (_inp.keyDown && isSnapped())
        {
            _moving = true;
            _stepsY ++;
            _directionInt = 270;
            _directionLabel = "Down";
            _speed = MOVEMENT_SPEED;
            if(_stepsY % 2 == 0)
            {gotoAndStop("WalkDown1");} else {gotoAndStop("WalkDown2");}
        }
```

Booya